# How Setting the API Key & initializing the library skobbler Android?

Tags: android

I'm new in this group , now I'm trying to do and to develop an app android using Skobbler but I have problem for Setting the API Key & initializing the library .... I 'm following http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec001.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements {  
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        String mapResDirPath = "../../../../assets/";   
        final SKPrepareMapTextureThread prepThread = new SKPrepareMapTextureThread(this, mapResDirPath, "SKMaps.zip", this); 

        prepThread.start();
    }
}
```

Thank you 
Fred,

Answer (score 0):

Just get demo project and look to Splash activity code with initialization and preparing map resourses before start activity with map:
http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download